# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'StartDate' property

Tags: php, datetime, soap

I need to create a SOAP request which looks like this:

```
<s:element name="GetOrders">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Token" type="s:string"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Context" type="s:string"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="StartDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EndDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IncludeFulfilledOrders" type="s:boolean"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ProductNumber" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I've created a class for the variables:

```
class GetOrders {
    public $Token = "THE_TOKEN"; // string
    public $Context='THE_CONTEXT'; // string
    public $StartDate=""; // dateTime
    public $EndDate=""; // dateTime
    public $IncludeFulfilledOrders=true; // boolean
    public $ProductNumber=""; // string
}
```

The function that runs the soap call looks like this:

```
public function GetOrders(GetOrders $parameters) {
return $this->__soapCall('GetOrders',array('parameters'=>array($parameters)),       array(
        'uri' => 'http://www.domain.net/',
        'soapaction' => ''
       )
  );
}
```

I'm getting the error: 
SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'StartDate' property in...

Here is a var_dump of the $parameters I am passing:

```
object(GetOrders)#1 (6) {
  ["Token"]=>
  string(17) "THE_TOKEN"
  ["Context"]=>
  string(7) "THE_CONTEXT"
  ["StartDate"]=>
  string(25) "2012-09-01T00:00:00-05:00"
  ["EndDate"]=>
  string(25) "2012-09-30T00:00:00-05:00"
  ["IncludeFulfilledOrders"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["ProductNumber"]=>
  string(10) "P-PRODUCT"
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue with the StartDate is.  I believe the format is correct. I don't know much about SOAP though so I apologize if this is a newb question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my function had an error in it that was throwing this.

This is how the function should have read.

```
public function GetOrders(GetOrders $parameters) {
return $this->__soapCall('GetOrders',array('parameters'=>$parameters),        array(
        'uri' => 'http://www.domain.com/',
        'soapaction' => ''
       )
  );
}
```

Notice the array('parameters'=>$parameters) is different than above.

It's always something little...

Answer (score 0):

The format might be wrong. Please check that whether you are sending the data in the right format. Also, check the generated stubs whether it is generated as per the WSDL definition.

You can log the request using

```
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
      // Add code to inspect/dissect/debug/adjust the XML given in $request here

      // Uncomment the following line, if you actually want to do the request
      // return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
         $dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    try {
        $dom->loadXML($request);

    } catch (DOMException $de) {
        die ('Parse error with code ' . $de->code);
    }
    $request = $dom->saveXml();
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);

    }
```

Comment: I generated the php class directly from the WSDL definition.  I've never used the __doRequest function.  What would I be passing to the $request variable? It wouldn't be the actual XML would it?  That would take all day for me to write out and test.  The function I have is supposed to parse the array into XML.